# Convert a tsv file into csv

Tags: powershell

I have multiple .tsv file that I want to convert to a .csv file using Windows Powershell.

I used

```
Import-Csv C:\temp\file\users.txt -Delimiter "`t"
```

But I can't export to a csv file.

Can someone help please?

Comment: "I cant export to a csv file" - what have you tried? Also, are these multiple tsv files uniform (do they have the exact same headers)?

Comment: @CalinMihai24 look for `export-csv` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv You have to import then export.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen He has indicated that he was able to import it. Thats a step in the right direction.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, yes, they got the same header. The thing is I am able to import them, but they are not object, so I can manipulating them with Powershell.

Comment: If `Import-Csv` is not giving you the expected result, could you post a sample tsv in your question?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`Export-Csv` cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) to export the data.

Now, `Import-Csv` only takes one file at a time, so wrap that in a loop or the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\temp\file\ -Filter *.txt |ForEach-Object {
  Import-Csv $_.FullName -Delimiter "`t"
} |Export-Csv C:\path\to\output.csv -Delimiter "`t" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it finally worked, but is it possible to  convert the output.csv it to a .tsv file?

Comment: You can use ``-Delimiter "`t"`` with `Export-Csv` as well :-)

Comment: | export-csv -delimiter "`t" -path output.csv -notype